# Convert Arrays of Reals into an Equivalent Array of Complex

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

Given a collection of $n$ real number arrays of length $m$, for example:

$$[r_{11},\ \dots, r_{1m}]$$
$$\vdots$$
$$[r_{n1},\ \dots, r_{nm}]$$
is it possible to transform the entire collection into one equivalent complex number array of length $m$, for example, $[c_1,\ \dots, c_m]$?

Also, the solution should be the same regardless of the row order in the collection.

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalent" here?

Comment: Equivalent in the sense that the information content of the real arrays is transformed but preserved.

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"?  There is indeed a bijection between the sets you have indicated.

Comment: In fact, you can compress everything into a single real number by using Cantor's interlace-the-decimals trick. The result will not make much _arithmetic_ sense, but that doesn't seem to be part of your specification.

Comment: I'm looking for a function or process that can collapse those arrays into a single array. You might think of the arrays as collections of variables gathered at different times, so I want to remove the dimension of time while preserving the information in some form.

Comment: What's a "real number array"? That expression combines a mathematical term ("real number") and a computer term ("array") and doesn't make sense the way those terms are usually used in those fields, since computers can't store arbitrary real numbers. Do you mean an array on a computer or just a tuple of real numbers?

Comment: To expand upon joriki's point, you must either mean "floating point" instead of "real number", or you must mean "tuple" instead of "array".

Comment: I tend to think in computer programming terms. My meaning was a one-dimensional array of real numbers.

Comment: More accurately, I was thinking of one-dimensional arrays of floating point numbers.

Comment: I take it that you're probably then also thinking of a pair of floating point numbers when you write "complex number". In that case, the answer for $n\gt2$ is "no", since the array of "complex numbers" has only as many bits as two arrays of "real numbers", and the "information content" is given by the number of bits. For $n=2$ the answer is "yes" since you can combine $r(0,k)$ and $r(1,k)$ into $c_k$.

Comment: Thank you. I have a somewhat related question but I'll use another thread and try to be more precise in the description.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes if $n=1$, because a real number is also a complex number.
- Yes if $n=2$, because a pair of real numbers $r(0,k)$ and $r(1,k)$ can be represented by one complex number.
- No if $n>2$, because there is no natural way to represent three or more real numbers as a single complex number (unnatural ways include mashing two single-precision numbers into double-precision, but this is silly, and does not go far.)